# Save a document with Spotfire scripting

Tags: scripting, ironpython, spotfire

When I create a Sportfire (6.5.0) script with the following code:

```
Application.Save()
```

I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Attempt to execute a ProgressOperation in the context of a document transaction.

at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.ProgressService.ExecuteWithProgressCancelable(String title, String description, ProgressOperation operation, Boolean showCancelButton)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.ProgressService.ExecuteWithProgress(String title, String description, ProgressOperation operation)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication.Save()
at _stub_$39##39(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object )
at Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.MatchCaller.Call2[T0,T1,TRet](Func`4 target, CallSite site, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.CallSite`1.UpdateAndExecute(Object[] args)
at Microsoft.Scripting.Actions.UpdateDelegates.Update2[T,T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at <module>$37##37(Closure , Scope , LanguageContext )
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport.IronPythonScriptEngine.ExecuteForDebugging(String scriptCode, Dictionary`2 scope, Stream outputStream)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Scripting.ScriptService.ExecuteForDebugging(String scriptCode, Dictionary`2 scope, Stream outputStream)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Scripting.ScriptManager.<>c__DisplayClass14.<ExecuteScriptForDebugging>b__f()
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Commands.CommandHistory.Transaction(Executor executor, Boolean visible, Boolean sticky, Guid stickyGuid)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Commands.CommandHistory.Transaction(String displayName, Executor executor)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.DocumentModel.DocumentNode.Transaction(String displayName, Executor executor)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Scripting.ScriptManager.ExecuteScriptForDebugging(String scriptCode, Dictionary`2 scriptArguments, String& output)
at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Framework.Scripting.ScriptEditDialog.RunButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: Is that all that is in your script? Can you share the full script if not? Is "Application" set up as the AnalysisApplication class which holds the Save() method?

Comment: @clesiemo3 thanks for your response. Yes that is the full script.
When I run 
`print type(Application)`
it gives me: `<type 'RichAnalysisApplication'>`

On further inspection: when the exact same code is run from a file opened from the Library, it seems to work fine...?

Comment: if you are still using 6.5, you'll need to update due to a critical security flaw in the Spotfire product.  See support center for details.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have "script author" rights.  check your id in the admin manager.

Comment: I have reproduced error above on version 5.5 where script author rights are not intruduced yet so I dont think that is the solution here.

Comment: @JacekSierajewski no, then probably not.